# How do get optionsText inside a parent?

Tags: knockout.js

When using a simple `observerableArray` with a normal `options` binding, it works pretty well. However, I'm not sure what the best way is to set this within a parent.

HTML:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: someParent">
    <select data-bind="options: $parent.choices, 
                       optionsText: $data, 
                       value: $parent.choice">
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.someParent= ko.observableArray(["Whatevs"]);
    this.choices = ko.observableArray(["one", "two", "three"]);
    this.choice = ko.observable("two");
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Were this not inside a foreach, the select element would autoselect "two" from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from documentation:

> If your parameter’s value is an array of strings, you don’t need to give any other parameters.

Dropping the `optionsText` parameter will give you the desired result.

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.choices, 
                   value: $parent.choice">
</select>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/bkJNp/)